# Why files referenced in HTML not found?

Tags: javascript, html, directory-structure

I am referencing some javascript files in the HTML, but in Chrome's console, it says that they're not found.

[image: Console errors]
[image: libs directory]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/stats.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/dat.gui.js"></script>
```

Comment: The only reason must be because the files either do not exits or the path is wrong!

Comment: try  this man `<script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/three.js"></script>`

Comment: The files exist. I don't see how the path is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, uzaif, I thought I tried the before, but now it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is with your script tag is that you forgot to specify the
>   current directory

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/three.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to delete / ..maybe it should be the problem ..or check the filenames ..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but uzaif answered it in comments.